# svnadmin dump skip revision

Tags: svn

Are there any dangers of skipping a particular revision if I know we don't need it when using svnadmin dump?

I'm migrating to a new SVN server, and one foolish commit of about 1gb worth of images is causing the dump to take forever.  Furthermore, I'm setting up an svnsync to do incremental syncs on each commit, but my initial sync ends up timing out, just on that particular revision.

If I do a dump up to that revision, then do an incremental dump thereafter, could this in any way affect revisions after that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to be completly safe run as follows:

```
svnadmin dump /your/repo| svndumpfilter exclude path | svnadmin load /new/repo
```

take a backup of old repo and when you are sure all is fine just switch it with new one.

more about svndumpfilter [here](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.5/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.commands.c.exclude.html); keywords for google: *[svn obliterate](http://www.google.com/search?q=svn+obliterate)* - maybe some day will be implemented...

Comment: thanks, i'll check that out when I get the chance and report back